# Who is user 19341?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I found that Google Chrome omnibox suggests me "english stackexchange users 19341" when I search for "English stac".

This is interesting; who is this "users 19341" and more importantly, **why is he/she given special status by Google search?**

[image]

Comment: try googling it.

Comment: Perhaps he is a [Panda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda).

Comment: Well they're no moon

Comment: [Who is Keyser Soze?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYXXhn9fMYs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to [this chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/conversation/user19341):

> Dunno if you know, but I figured out who recently deleted user19341 is.
> Arch.
> Oh! Why did he delete himself?

This was an active member called "Arch" and according to [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=site:english.stackexchange.com+%22user19341%22) he indeed left lots of comments and was pretty active.

The Chrome omnibox suggestions are based on your own activities, for example for me it did not show what you saw, so it probably means that your Google searches involved content of that user.

Comment: It actually showed up for me, and I've only visited English.SE a handful of times, usually because of the Hot Network Question list.  And I don't recall every seeing that user, but was the 3rd item on the list, not the 2nd.

Comment: @psubsee2003 weird, dunno how their algorithm works then. Maybe recent searches from other people affect as well?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing it as well, and only go there once in a blue moon.

Comment: Omnibox suggestions take into account user activities, *in addition to* everyone else's searches. E.g., if you type "chess bobby" you will get something with Fischer and Spassky in the autocomplete, whether or not your searches ever involved chess.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, that doesn't explain why he is favored by Google Omnibox...